# Hide the background image on crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, background-image

i have crystal report on which i have added background image say watermark image. I want to set it's visibility depend on condition true or false.How can i hide image from c# code while loading report.I have tried this but not working.
Any solution for this?

```
((PictureObject)MyReport.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Picture2"]).Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way is to add a parameter to the report and suppress the image based on the parameter value.

Comment: I agree, much better and much easier to use a discrete parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.
By setting width and height of image to 0.

```
((PictureObject)reprt_changed.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Picture2"]).Width=0;
((PictureObject)reprt_changed.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Picture2"]).Height = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to its own section, set the section's property to 'underlay following sections', then suppress the section as desired.